# Example of $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\circ g$ is bijective but $g\circ f$ is not bijective

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples, function-and-relation-composition

I am seeking functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\circ g$ is a bijection and $g\circ f$ is not a bijection.

Here is what I have done so far in terms of gathering clues:

- If $f\circ g$ is bijective, then it is both injective and surjective
  by definition, which makes it necessary that $g$ is injective and $f$
  is surjective.
- If $g\circ f$ is not a bijection, then it is necessary
  that $f$ is not a bijection or $g$ is not a bijection (since the
  composition of bijections is a bijection). Combined with the previous bullet point, it means that $f$ is not an injection or $g$ is not a surjection.

An example of $f$ that is surjective but not injective is $x^3-x$, and an example of $g$ that is injective but not surjective is $2^x$. These $f$ and $g$ don't seem to help in this case though.

Could someone provide examples of suitable functions $f$ and $g$? I have also checked the classic books *Counterexamples in Topology* and *Counterexamples in Analysis* without any progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick any injective, non-surjective $g$. Make sure that $f$ is an inverse of $g$ on the range of $g$. That's all you need.

For instance:
$$
g(x)=e^x\\
f(x)=\cases{\ln(x)& if $x>0$\\0 & otherwise}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can take$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x+2&\text{ if }x<-1&\\-x&\text{ if }x\in[-1,1]\\x-2&\text{ if }x>1\end{cases}$$which is surjective, but not injective. And now define $f(x)$ as the smallest real solution of the equation $g(y)=x$, that is$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x-2&\text{ if }x<1\\x+2&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $f$ is injective, but not surjective (its range is $\Bbb R\setminus[-1,3)$). So, $f\circ g$ is not a bijection. But $g\circ f$ is the identity function.